# Eclipse not running java program

Tags: java, eclipse, path, classpath, windows-10

I have recently upgraded OS to Windows 10 and now I am not able to run any java program in Eclipse IDE. I have set PATH variable in the Systems Environment Variables.

I have also tried installing Java in other drive and set path but still this error persists.

Below is the error message I am receiving while running a basic java program-

**Exception occurred executing command line.
Cannot run program ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_01\bin\javaw.exe"" (in directory "F:\Project\Java Practive"): CreateProcess error=1392, The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable**

However when I am running same program using cmd it's running fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a digging deep I am able to find the solution-
1. Downloaded Eclipse IDE for 64 bit Windows 10
2. Downloaded Java 1.8 64 bit

Now I am having a 64 bit trio (OS, IDE, Java)